# Should there be doubled stun requests in WebRTC?

Tags: firefox, webrtc, stun

Using https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/ on Firefox 102.6.0 ESR and gathering the wireshark traces shows that for each STUN server configured, **there are 2 outgoing requests** per network interface. The same behavior is observed in my app using WebRTC.

Is there a specific point to why Firefox does it twice everytime?

Comment: I can confirm the duplicate stun requests as well on my Windows desktop with FF. Having built a simple WebRTC prototype, I found a handful of behavior differences in WebRTC between Safari (mac), Firefox, and Chrome/Edge that make for interesting bugs to deal with.  You got three choices. 1) Ignore it, it's a benign bug. 2) File a bug in Firefox. Maybe they fix it- good luck. 3) Build and debug the Firefox source and submit a pull request with the fix.  There's probably a fourth option which is to find a mailing list or a developer contact within Mozilla sources specific to Media or WebRTC.

Answer (score 3):

I see that they are also generating both UDP and TCP Host candidates which Chrome doesn't do. I suspect that might be related: they're making two STUN requests, one over UDP and another over TCP. It does seem unnecessary though.